# Avatars : default image

Tags: php, html

i would like to make a simple avatar system for my users.

Usage is simple, every uploaded avatar image is named by user, for example:

`<a>...$username.'.jpg';..</a>`

so there is really no need for database. 
When user is logged in, I just append the filetype to the already (from database) required username.

What concerns me here is the default image, which is used before user sets his own image. What is the best way to handle this? Is there a possiblity to create / copy default image to users avatar folder when user account is created?

I know that I can achieve this using database (default value) or checking if user image is set etc. but i want to keep it as simple as possible.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You could call a php file instead that checks if the $filename.jpg exists and if that fails outputs a default image

Comment: did you have a look at Gravatar? http://en.gravatar.com/

Comment: I'd do what gunnx suggests aswell.

Comment: If you also use htaccess to rewrite the path so it looks nicer e.g. <img src="/img/avatar/<username>.jpg" /> and that would be sent to something like avatar.php?username=<username>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple example of what the file would do. I'd suggest making it more secure of course.

```
$filename = $_GET["avatar"];
$path = 'path/to/your/files';
if (!file_exists($path.$filename.'.jpg'))
{
   $filename = "default";
}
Header('Content-type: image/jpg');
readfile($path.$filename.'.jpg');
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if the user's profile picture exists on the file system:

- If it exists: display it.
- If it doesn't: display the default image that is stored in one single place. No need to copy it.

I recommend saving the image name in the database, **with its extension**. People may want to upload a PNG or GIF image, rather than the classical JPG.

Answer (score 1):

A simple example of what you are trying to do could be...

1. When a user registers in your site, he or she can upload or not an image.
2. Make a validation in the process to know if there is an image to be uploaded or not. Also, if there is a file in the process, validate it's extension (declare and array with the extensions you want to allow and compare with the incomming file).
3. If the user that is registering doesn't upload an image, in your server, create a default image for example: "users/default.jpg". So in the insert to you db, you must put in your imaginary "image_name" column: default and in your "image_ext" column: .jpg
4. If the user that is registering uploads an image in the process, in your server (when you validated the extension and size) create for example: "users/1.jpg" which "1" is the userid, and also in your insert to the db put in your imaginary "image_name" column: 1 and in your "image_ext" column: .jpg
5. To retrieve the image, just do a kind of `select * from` of the userid you want and just put in your html: `echo "<img src='users/".$row['image_name'].$row['image_ext']."'/>";` and that's all, you are done.